# Set CSS class dynamically without template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For each component with prefix `mycomponent-` I would like to add a class with the name of the component. I don't want to have to modify the component in order to do this.

My first thought was to use mixins and somehow add the class in `beforeCreate` but I haven't managed to add classes dynamically without using the template.

Do I have to use `$el.classList.add(this.$options.name)` in `beforeUpdate` or similar? Is there some more Vue-ish way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, wrapped up as plugin:

```js
const addComponentNameAsClass = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    const fn = Vue.prototype.$mount;
    Vue.prototype.$mount = function() {
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
      if (this.$options._componentTag?.startsWith("mycomponent-")) {
        this.$el.classList.add(this.$options._componentTag);
      }
    }
  }
}

Vue.use(addComponentNameAsClass);

// that's all you need
// see it working:

['a', 'b', 'foo', 'whatever'].forEach(type => {
  Vue.component('mycomponent-' + type, {
    template: '<div><slot /></div>'
  })
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
[class^="mycomponent-"] {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.mycomponent-a {
  border-color: red;
}

.mycomponent-b {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<div id="app">
  <mycomponent-a>I should get a red border.</mycomponent-a>
  <mycomponent-b>I should get a blue one.</mycomponent-b>
  <mycomponent-foo>bar</mycomponent-foo>
  <mycomponent-whatever>Meh.</mycomponent-whatever>
</div>
```

Notes:

- you should not expect this to work on Vue3. Why? Because whenever you're using internal props starting with `_` Vue does not guarantee they'll still be there in the next major version update. But, on the other hand, the `name` of the component is not saved anywhere else (other than `$options._componentTag`).
- the above won't work if you use components as `<MycomponentA></MycomponentA>`. However, you can swiftly get around it by running the value of `$options._componentTag` through a helper function (e.g: `kebabCase` from `lodash`).

  - note on note: if you want the added class to always be `kebab-case`, you'll have run the value passed to `.classList.add()` through `kebabCase`, as well). Otherwise, `<MycomponentA>` will add `MycomponentA` class and `<mycomponent-a>` will add `mycomponent-a` class, for obvious reasons.

Ref. *"Vue-ish way"*: whatever the end goal of applying this *"component"* class is, chances are it can be achieved cleaner.
The very idea of placing classes denominating component type doesn't feel Vue-ish at all.
It feels WordPress-ish and Angular-ish. To me, at least.

Comment: Your example works, but when I try to integrate the solution into my projects I run into problems. Not sure if some other libraries (Vuetify perhaps) uses the same method of rewriting $mount and cause some conflict.

Comment: I found the fix. If the overridden $mount() function returns the value from fn.apply(this, arguments); everything works as expected!